# How to chain promises with arrays

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3, promise, aws-lambda

Problem:  Create an AWS Lambda function to resize uploaded S3 pictures using Node 4.3 and graphics magic.

My Problem:  I cannot figure out how to integrate an array of picture objects into the promise flow.  All of the stack examples that I can find show an array of object promisified when all data is known.  But I need to read the image data first and then pass it to the resize function.

The function below completes before resizePicture resolves.  I know the issue is not returning Promises and resolving in the correct order.  I'm stumped.

```
var pictureSizes = [
  {width: 100, size: 'thumbnail', suffix: '_t'},
  {width: 300, size: 'small', suffix: '_s'},
  {width: 600, size: 'medium', suffix: '_m'},
  {width: 1000, size: 'large', suffix: '_l'}
];

exports.handler = function(event, context) {

  var srcBucket = event.Records[0].s3.bucket.name;.
  var srcKey = decodeURIComponent(event.Records[0].s3.object.key.replace(/\+/g, " "));
  var dstBucket = srcBucket + "pictures";
  var typeMatch = srcKey.match(/\.([^.]*)$/);
  var fileName = path.basename(srcKey);

  downloadImage({ Bucket: srcBucket, Key: srcKey})
  .then(result => pictureSizes.map(picture => resizePicture(result, picture)))
  .then(result => saveImage(result, dstBucket, fileName))
  .catch(err => console.log('error', err))
}

function downloadImage(params) {
  console.log('download Image', params);
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    s3.getObject(params, function(err, data) {
      if (err) {
        reject(err);
      }
      resolve(data);
    })
  });
}

function resizePicture(result, picture) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    const extension = result.ContentType.split('/')[1];
    gm(result.Body)
      .resize(picture.width)
      .toBuffer(extension, function(err, buffer) {
        if (err) {
          reject(err);
        } else {
          resolve({
            key: `${picture.suffix}.${extension}`,
            binary: buffer,
            ContentType: result.contentType
          })
        }
      });
  })
}

function saveImage(result, dstBucket, fileName) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    s3.putObject({
      Bucket: dstBucket,
      Key: `${fileName}${result.key}`,
      Body: result.binary,
      ContentType: result.ContentType
    }, function(err, data) {
      if (err) {
        reject(err);
      }
      resolve(data);
    })
  })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, you've almost got it! You need to create a watcher for an array of promises you generate here: `pictureSizes.map(picture => resizePicture(result, picture))`.

Try [Bluebird's Promise.map](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.map.html), and your line can read:

```
.then(result => Promise.map(pictureSizes, picture => resizePicture(result, picture)))
```

And if you want to not have any nested functions, [#bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) is what you want:

```
.then(result => Promise.map(pictureSizes, resizePicture.bind(null, result)))
```

Comment: That was it, thank you!  If you know how to make it without the nested call, I'd be interested... trying to be a better functional programmer.